# React Native error when I add icons from react-native-vector-icons

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-vector-icons

I'm building my first app with React Native.
I'm using react-navigation bottomTabNavigator and when I added the icons on the tabs, my app won't work on the Android.
iOS is working ok.

[Here is the gist with my Menu.js code](https://gist.github.com/jdalri/5135af65a01f3ae43fcf78c0b7f78253)

Even when I comment out the lines that use icons (the icons itself, the imports) the erros continues.
But I don't understand what is going on, because the error started on the Android when I started to use the icons.

In the iOS, everything works perfectly.

Any help?

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked. No errors. Take a look at this thread and see if any of the answers suit you: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/401

Also, what version of react-native are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have also used react-native-vector-icons so , You just need to run :

1. npm install react-native-vector-icons,
2. adding this line

- apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

Here :android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score -1):

In android you have to include `icon="require('some path like images')"`, then it work. for example:

```
 tabs: [
      {
        label: 'One',
        screen: 'Screen1',
        icon: require('./images/icon1.png'),
        selectedIcon: require('./images/icon1_selected.png'),
        title: 'Screen One'
      },

    ]
```